# Apache authentication and ASP

Tags: apache, session, authentication, cookies, asp-classic

Is it possible to logon a user with Apache authentication and use the same cookies to logon user to an ASP site?

Here is how the server configuration looks:

`Browser` > `Apache` > `IIS (running inside a private network)`

Currently when we hit the site, it shows the apache logon prompt. After user gets authenticated successfully it lands to login page of an ASP application running on IIS on a separate machine. Here user have to login again to get into the ASP application.

What I want to achieve is to have the user log in once through apache authentication, store the session in a cookie and use the same session to log on to ASP application.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you saying that the only machine talking to IIS is the apache server, the browser can't access it directly?

Comment: Borwser can access the site running on IIS. But no one can log on to machine (RDC) directly from outside.